# Elasticsearch doesn't find values containing "-"

Tags: elasticsearch

I ran into an issue where elasticsearch is not able to find indexed categories that contain an "-" in their slug. The category given is "wc-sitze". When I query for "wc", the category is found, and when I query for "sitze", it is also found, however when I query for the whole thing "wc-sitze", it is not found. I have checked with several other categories, and it seems that always the "-" is messing it up.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please share your mapping and search query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using the text field with [default analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) `standard` which removes the special char like `-`. you need to change the analyzer to make it work.

Comment: @mehlichmeyer glad you figured it out, can u upvote and accept answer as it points the mistake :D

Comment: for filtering on category you should probably use a keyword instead of a text

Comment: @Prerna unfortunately I was too quick to consider the problem solved. It didn't work yet. I am checking a few things and will come back to this topic with additional info. Thanks though!

Comment: @mehlichmeyer please follow what Jaycreation suggested